# Pole on the contour $\oint_{|z|=3} \frac{(z-1)^2}{(z-2)^2(z-3)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How would you calculate the following closed contour integral where one of the poles is on the contour?$$\oint_{|z|=3} \frac{(z-1)^2}{(z-2)^2(z-3)} dz$$

I've only been given questions where the poles are either inside and/or outside the contour, but never on the contour.

Comment: Take half of residue

Comment: Take half of the residue at z=3 or at z=3 and z=2?

Comment: At $z=3$. Motivation is that we deform contour, so it contains singularity inside and that deformation should be subtracted from result, so half of residue instead of full one.

Comment: This is easy: It's not defined.

Comment: The contour needs to be deformed so that the contour does not contain the pole.